# What is the best way to check for null in Using statement with streamreader?

Tags: c#, .net-core, streamreader, httpwebresponse

I have a HttpWebResponse and StreamReader resharper is indicating that my httpResponse.GetResponseStream() may be null but I'm not sure of the proper syntax.

```
using(var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
     if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
     { 
          //This line is where Resharper Is complaining
          using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
          {
               var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
               ...
          }
     }
     else
     {...
```

Comment: check it before hand.

Comment: Besides the duplicate, tell ReSharper to shut up :) that's a useless warning

Comment: What do you mean by "the best way"? Just compare the result to `null` and if that comparison returns `false`, the object isn't null...

Comment: Sorry, i thought because it was a stream that i couldn't check before hand otherwise it would have read to the end and then would no longer be available and that the using took care of disposing etc... but i see this is pretty obvious now. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check that `httpResponse.GetResponseStream()` doesn't return a null value:

```cs
using(var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            // Line reached only if httpResponse.GetResponseStream() isn't null
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: you can reduce unnecessary nesting by inverting your `if` statements and using `return`:    `if (responseStream == null) return;`. That helps you avoid the dreaded [pyramid of doom](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CoYUZ3cUIAEx7XR.jpg).

Comment: I was kinda following the style of the code that was already there, but yeah, this is starting to look quite nested and would benefit from some tidying.

Comment: Fair enough. Although OP's case is slightly different because it has an `else` clause (and since we don't know what's in it, we can't say if the else clause can be removed with this same refactoring technique). My comment was simply in the spirit of sharing knowledge and making code simpler/easier to read. :)

Comment: In general, you are right. But in this case, I think this code is fine because it is still easy to read and because it will work by copy&paste regardless of context – if I write an empty `return` and the method that contains this code happens to return something, then my code won't work exactly as it is. In any case, given how simple this code is, I think that either way would be fine here, but I appreciate the feedback for the future!

Comment: Yes generally i follow that but there's more going on if the status code isn't OK then i check the error and handle the notifications to the appropriate teams/logs and it sill makes sense to keep it all together in this short method than splitting it out as it's all logically connected. Thanks for the note though!